# BitmapCache poor performance while resizing

Tags: wpf, caching, bitmapcache

I have a `ListView` with different complex `ListViewItem` containers consisting of images, shadow effects, blur effects.. etc. Rendering these containers in large amounts heavily reduces performance, especially since i'm using a blur overlay frame on top of the `ListView`. Which is why in this case i'm setting `CacheMode` to `BitmapCache` (improves performance by up to 15x the fps).

```
<Border.CacheMode>
    <BitmapCache />
</Border.CacheMode>
```

The problem is that i use a `WrapPanel` and a `ValueConverter` to dynamically resize and fit these containers into the `WrapPanel` so that they completely fill the space in either horizontal or tile views. Apparently, that doesn't work well with caching and it produces severe lags/stalls (frame drops to 0).

Currently my 3 options are:

- Disable caching (and live with almost 15fps)
- Disable resizing (looks unacceptable)
- Disable caching and resizing only when resizing window (still performs bad but it's the best option i have)

My questions:

- Why do i get these huge drops in performance while resizing with caching vs without caching?
- Am i misusing caching or doing it wrong?
- Is there a better way of fixing this mess without compromises?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. After a lot of reading and experimenting, i figured two things:

- First, `Caching` should not be used on elements that resize frequently, especially if they're too many (couldn't find out why). So, i basically cached fixed size child elements instead.
- And that reminded me of `Virtualization` which was exactly what i was missing but didn't know was supported in `WPF Lists`.

With some more optimizations, now, i can resize the window buttery smooth.